# Why is viewWillAppear firing twice

Tags: iphone

Why in my UIViewController the function

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

fired at two times.... Is it wrong ?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: 2 times when? maybe you are calling is 2 times? :)

Comment: I've never seen this happen.  Can you post the code?

Answer (score 2):

I used to have the same problem. If you are using Navigation Based project, the IB sets by default your RootViewController as your first view on the NavigationController. So if you push the same view again on the NavigationController in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, it will fire ViewWillApper for the second time.

If this is not the case, try putting a break point and discover when it fires it.